# How can I add up multiple columns in PHP and SQL with the same id?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum, addition

I have two columns in a MySQL table, one called "Total Experience" and one called "id"

Is there a way to add up the value of Total Experience and put it in a variable for all users with the same id?

Example: There are 3 users: Steve, Jack, and Sam

```
Steve has the id of 1 and Total Experience of 500
Jack has the id of 1 and Total Experience of 400
Sam has the id of 2 and Total Experience of 700
```

Is there a way to select and add up Steve and Jack's Total Experience in a SQL query, as they have the same id?

Comment: Why does the title say you're adding multiple columns, but you're only adding one column?

Comment: ^ I noticed that as well.  Should be add up multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` to aggregate rows by a column.

```
SELECT id, SUM(`Total Experience`) AS experience
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY id
```